# Sort items in a list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a string list in a C# ASP.net project i am working on. 
the contents in the list look something like below:

```
Apple,1,monday
Banana,5,monday
Pear,4,tuesday
Apple,2,tuesday,
Banana,7,tuesday
Orange,6,wednesday
Apple,9,thursday,
Banana,2,friday
```

The list contains a type of fruit item, the quantity of that particular fruit and the day that fruit and quantity is needed. 
What i want to do is to sort the list according to the type of fruit then days from monday to friday with each quanity for each day. 
For example for the fruit item "Apple" i want to have a table entry that looks like this.

```
Apple,1,2,0,9,0
```

The item Apple is sorted so that the quantity of apples required for Monday is shown and if there is no quantity of apples for a certain day eg Wednesday and Friday then display a 0.

Id also like the same applied to all the items in the list etc o the same for Banana, pear, orange, or any other fruit that might be in the list.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

So far ive got he code below, its a messy approach that i cant get working. 
the original list is called "itemsFruitMon" and the sorted list ive called "formatted". Its not a great approach and ive become stuck with how to continue.

```
            foreach (var item in itemsFruitMon)
        {
            foreach (var itemComp in itemsFruitMon)
            {
                if(item.Split(',')[0]==itemComp.Split(',')[0])
                {

                    if (itemComp.Contains("monday"))
                    {
                        formatted.Add(item.Split(',')[0] + "," + item.Split(',')[1].Split(',')[0]);  
                       // formatted.Add(item.Split(',')[0]+","+item.Split(',')[1].Split(',')[0]);                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        formatted.Add(item.Split(',')[0] + "," + 0);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: We can help you.  Can you share with us what you've tried so far, and describe where specifically you're stuck?

Comment: Hello Amy, Thanks for your response. The only thing ive managed to do with the list is get the total number of fruit regardless of the day or fruit type. I am at a loss when trying to sort the list the way i want. I know what i want just not sure how to get it. Thank you

Comment: So which part of this exactly has to do with sorting, and what code do you already have?

Comment: @cfcorp We are happy to help you, but we are less keen on doing work *for* you.  Please share with us what you have.

Comment: Have you considered using a class? Properties could be Name (string), and then a bunch of int properties qtyMon, qtyTue, qtyWed, qtyThu, qtyFri.

Comment: Id start by thinking about what type of data structure you'll need to hold the data you want of 'Apple,1,2,0,9,0'. Your own class with these fields might be helpful and then you can create objects of this type and populate the fields of the object.

Comment: ive just added what i have so far which is far less than ideal as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do any sorting here.

The number of weekdays is always 7. You need 0 for days when fruit does not arrive. So for each fruit you need a 7 element array or list of ints. Each weekday name is the index in that array or list.

The parser would roughly look like this:

```
var fruitDays = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
foreach (var line in listOfLines)
{
    var fields = line.Split(',');
    var fruit = fields[0];
    var quantity = int.Parse(fields[1]);
    var weekday = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), fields[2], true); // Case-weekday insensitive parsing. Keep in mind that Monday=0 and Sunday=0 here 
    if (!fruitDays.ContainsKey(fruit)) fruitDays.Add(fruit, new int[7]);
    fruitDays[fruit][weekday] = quantity;
}
```

Comment: Hello,thanks for the reply and for your help. Is 'WeekdayToIndex' a built in class or library as its not recognized by C# ASP.net? thanks

Comment: Thank you Optional Option, that worked perfectly. i had to change "WeekdayToIndex" to var weekday = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), (day))); Where 'day' equals the day value for the particular field. Also i changed the days to show the first letter in CAPS, e.g. monday to Monday. Thanks so so so much!!!!!

Comment: Added proper weekday parsing. You should use DayOfWeek enum carefully as in your question Monday was assumed to have index 0 and  DayOfWeek enum starts from Sunday=0

Answer (score 2):

Try IComparable and then create a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>() {
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Apple", quantity = 1, day = "monday"},
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Banana", quantity = 5, day = "monday"},
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Pear", quantity = 4, day = "tuesday"},
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Apple", quantity = 2, day = "tuesday"},
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Banana", quantity = 7, day = "tuesday"},
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Orange", quantity = 6, day = "wednesday"},
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Apple", quantity = 9, day = "thursday"},
                new Fruit() { fruit =  "Banana", quantity = 2, day = "friday"}
            };

            List<Fruit> results = fruits.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, List<Fruit>> dict = results.GroupBy(x => x.fruit, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
    }
    public class Fruit : IComparable<Fruit>
    {
        public string fruit { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        dayofweek date { get; set; }
        public string day {
            get { return date.ToString();}
            set { date = (dayofweek)Enum.Parse(typeof(dayofweek), value);}
        }

        enum dayofweek
        {
            sunday = 0,
            monday = 1,
            tuesday = 2,
            wednesday = 3,
            thursday = 4,
            friday = 5,
            saturday = 6
        }

        public int CompareTo(Fruit other)
        {
            if (this.fruit != other.fruit)
            {
                return this.fruit.CompareTo(other.fruit);
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.date != other.date)
                {
                    return this.date.CompareTo(other.date);
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.quantity.CompareTo(other.quantity);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```